# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long. with post ID

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, validation

What's wrong with my program? I get error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long.
```

And don't know how to solve it... On the stack trace the only class written by me is

```
myapp.spring.controllers.PostFormController.processForm(PostFormController.java:66)
```

And this line is

```
validator.validate(p, result);
```

Post.java

```
// imports

@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class Post implements Serializable
{
        /* **********************************
         * ------------ fields ------------ *
         ************************************/
        /**
         *
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Past
        @Column(name="date")
        private Date date;

        @NotBlank
        @Size(min=3, max=20)
        @Column(name="author")
        private String author;

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name="content")
        private String content;

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name="topic")
        private String topic;

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name="thread_id")
        private long thread_id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="name")
        @Valid
        private PostType type;



        /* ***************************************
         * ---------- getters setters ---------- *
         *****************************************/
       // cut // 

}
```

blah blah blah can't add because of too much code in post :S

Comment: and `p` is a Long, right? What do you expect the validation of a Long variable to do? What don't you understand in the error message?

Comment: `p` is a `Post` type from http method POST
`public String processForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("post") Post p, BindingResult result)`

Comment: Show us the code of Post.

Comment: @JBNizet https://pastebin.com/pJhiAh3R

Comment: In your question. Not on pastebin. Use the edit link.

Comment: Added the code. I solved it with my friend's help: changed `long` to `Long`... Somebody can explain why is it make a difference?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information for us to understand and help with your issue. A complete code example with your Spring config file would be helpful. If the code is too long, try to get rid of the parts that do not affect the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem probably is this line:

```
@NotBlank
@Column(name="thread_id")
private long thread_id;
```

`NotBlank` has no sense on a field of type long. A long can't be blank or not blanked. Only a String can. Hence the error message:

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long

Comment: I added `NotBlank` because I thought lack of this causes that problem. Forgot to delete, sorry. The problem Was with `long`. I've changed to `Long` and now it works properly :D Thank you.